# Не проходит проверку XML

Tags: xml, битрикс, яндекс-маркет

Делаю выгрузку товаров в xml в битриксе с помощью модуля Маркет для бизнеса https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/yandex.market
Выгружается файл в xml формате

Заголовок фала в xml такой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
```

Проверяю эту ссылку на сервисе postman.co и выдаёт что это html файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы сервис читал не как html файл, а как xml?
Или другой вопроc: как в модуле Маркет для бизнеса поправить выгружаемый заголовок?

Comment: Другие скрины и ссылку могу скинуть в ЛС

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в php файле, который выгружает xml файл, такое:

```
<?
    Header('Pragma: public');
    Header('Cache-control: private');
    Header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    Header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=windows-1251");
    Header("Content-Length: 10052");
    Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=orders.xml");
?>
```

Кодировку, длину и название файла нужно указать свои.

Но проще было бы сохранить файл где-нибудь в /upload/ и дать на него ссылку.